# How to validate only part of a value I'm getting through a get request?

Tags: laravel

I want to get two values from a get request, and then I'll use explode to retrieve each of them separately. However, this means that the value I'm getting before using explode isn't unique to the table (since it's a compound, and therefore it's not an existing value in the table). How can use validate to avoid duplicate of it ?

I tried making the column unique using an SQL constraint, however this means I get an exception page when a user enters a duplicate. I would like to use validation instead so I get an error message.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'idProduit' => 'unique:stocks', 
            'produit' => 'required|unique:stocks',
            'quantite' => 'required'
        ]);
        $produit = explode("|",$request->get('produit'));
        $stock = new Stock;
        $stock->idProduit = $produit[0];
        $stock->produit = $produit[1];
        $stock->quantite = $request->input('quantite');
        $stock->save();

        return redirect('/stocks/')->with('success', 'Entrée de stock ajoutée à la base de données');
    }
```

I don't actually get any error message, but it is allowing me to add duplicates in the database, which I know why : the value is a compound that doesn't exist in the database, and so the unique validation I wrote cannot catch duplicate on just a part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way : Explode **before validation** and make new `$request` with 2 more fields . Thats Over !!

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $produit = explode("|",$request->get('produit'));
    $request->request->add(['idProduit' => $produit[0]]);
    $request->request->add(['produit' => $produit[1]]);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'idProduit' => 'unique:stocks', 
        'produit' => 'required|unique:stocks',
        'quantite' => 'required'
    ]);

    $stock = new Stock;
    $stock->idProduit = $produit[0];
    $stock->produit = $produit[1];
    $stock->quantite = $request->input('quantite');
    $stock->save();

    return redirect('/stocks/')->with('success', 'Entrée de stock ajoutée à la base de données');
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty, but not sure that explode accepts null in the second param.

Comment: :)It Accept any arguments but return an empty string for array[0] :: PHP.net Docs : If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE. If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, then an empty array will be returned, otherwise an array containing string will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You could create custom validation rule class or use Validator https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules.

Something like that:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'quantite' => 'required',
    'produit' => [
        'required', 
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $parts = explode('|', $value);

            if (!Stock::where('idProduit', $parts[0])->exists()) {
                $fail('idProduit already exists.');
            }

            if (!Stock::where('produit', $parts[1])->exists()) {
                $fail('produit already exists.');
            }
        }
    ],
])->validate();
```